# Linux Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, grep

I want to write an bash script in Linux with the folowing command `AWK` `SED` `grep` `curl` that find a specific Word and then count it.

Here is my Script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "URL:"
read url
urlsou=$(curl -s "$url")
result=$(awk '/test/ {f=1} /link/ {g=1} /WOW/ {h=1} !f && !g && h; /testend/ {f=0} /linkend/ {g=0} /wow/ {h=0}' | grep -o "WOW" | grep -c "WOW")
echo "Total :" "$result"
```

I get 0 when i use my script but when i use only `AWK` command as follow `AWK` with file that have HTML source `awk '/test/ {f=1} /link/ {g=1} /WOW/ {h=1} !f && !g && h; /testend/ {f=0} /linkend/ {g=0} /wow/ {h=0}' example | grep -o "WOW" | grep -c "WOW"` i get the right Answer.

here is my example file (but my real file is very complex):

```
WOW1wow
linklinkend
wow1WOWwow123WOW
testtestend
WOWWwow
link WOW test testend linkend wow
WOW2wow
link WOW 123 wow linkend
```

1. Try with `awk '/test/ {f=1} /link/ {g=1} /WOW/ {h=1} !f && !g && h; /testend/ {f=0} /linkend/ {g=0} /wow/ {h=0}' example | grep -o "WOW" | grep -c "WOW" example` result is **5**
2. Try with `awk '/test/ {f=1} /link/ {g=1} /WOW/ {h=1} !f && !g && h; /testend/ {f=0} /linkend/ {g=0} /wow/ {h=0}' example | grep -o "WOW" example` result is **4**
3. Try with Script result is **0**

**Correct answer is 5**

I think a Problem is with how can i pass urlsou variable to AWK in script or how can i create temporary file for urlsource.

What is my problem, How can i fix it without any programming Language or extra command?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm sorry, but it's completely unclear to me what you're asking. Perhaps you could try phrasing it differently? Thanks.

Comment: Your `result` line does not have any input as your test line using `example`as input.  Example: `result=$(awk '/test/ {f=1} /link/ {g=1} /WOW/ {h=1} !f && !g && h; /testend/ {f=0} /linkend/ {g=0} /wow/ {h=0}' example | grep -o "WOW" | grep -c "WOW" | grep -o "WOW" | grep -c "WOW")`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "URL:"
read url
urlsou=$(curl -s "$url")
# \b is "word boundaries"
result=$(sed 's/\b/\n/g' <<< "$urlsou" | grep -c WOW)
echo "Total :" "$result"
```

You have mentioned you don't want to learn another language, ok. But know that this is just a quick'n'dirty script, no more.

Comment: Thanks for your Help, I have write it in PERL but i want to use these command. can i write `awk '/test/ {f=1} /link/ {g=1} /WOW/ {h=1} !f && !g && h; /testend/ {f=0} /linkend/ {g=0} /wow/ {h=0}' <<< $urlsou`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extract of `man grep` :

> `-c`, `$--count`
>
> Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching lines for each input file.  With the `-v`, `--invert-match option`  (see  below), count non-matching lines.  (`-c` is specified by POSIX.)

Now here is the end of your command :

```
awk ... | grep -o "WOW" | grep -c "WOW" | grep -o "WOW" | grep -c "WOW"
```

Your last `grep -o "WOW"` will never work because it applies to a count.

Then I think it's getting a lot of pipe here. I'm sure it's possible to do that in a single awk ... However, you should give us more details on your input stream and on your expected output.

Comment: **FYI** i have edit my post. I dont have a problem with `AWK` command but in Script does not work correctly. When i use `AWK` command with File that consist a source then i get correct Answer but in **Script** :(

Comment: Ok, `grep -c` is sufficient, `grep -o` isn't useful ;)

Comment: Otherwise, check the permissions and path of file which is read by awk. And we need more details that will allow us to offer an optimal solution (example of input file and expected output).

Answer (score 0):

In you script awk reads from STDIN. You should pass the output of curl to it:

The easiest way is:

```
result=$(awk '/test/ {f=1} ...' $urlsou | ...
```

Another way is to pipe the output of curl directly to awk:

```
curl -s "$url" | awk '...' | ...
```